# Syntax Error in Ruby Gem term-ansicolor

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I have been following "[How-to: Use Cucumber with .NET and C# under IronRuby](http://blog.webintellix.com/2009/10/how-to-use-cucumber-with-net-and-c.html)" to set up Cucumber for .net on Windows. I had no problem installing Ruby, IronRuby and installing Cucumber, but when I came to this step, my troubles started:

> Check to see if Cucumber under IronRuby works: `icucumber –help`

Here `icucumber.bat` is a file we write to tell IronRuby where to find gems. I just copied the script from the link above and changed the directories to match my installation directories.

I first got a bunch of `require` errors, which I fixed by installing Cucumber (0.6.4) according to "[IRONRUBY: 0 TO CUCUMBER IN 15 MINUTES](http://blog.timwingfield.com/2010/07/16/ironruby-0-to-cucumber-in-15-minutes.html)":

> IronRuby isn’t quite ready for the latest version of Cucumber.

I also installed `term-ansicolor` by doing `gem install term-ansicolor`. At this point, although I got rid of the `require` errors, I got a new one:

```
c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/term-ansicolor-1.6.0/lib/term/ansicolor/rgb_triple.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected label
  def self.convert_value(color, max: 255)
                                ^
```

The file  is pointing to `rgb_triple.rb`, which came with the `term-ansicolor` gem. So I do not understand what could have caused this error.

Comment: When linking to a page, provide useful anchor text, so that those reading know where they're going to land. "[Don't use 'click here' as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)" and 
"[Clearly identify the target of each link](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-TECHS/#tech-meaningful-links)"

Comment: Thanks, shall keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that IronRuby isn't ready for the last version of `term-ansicolor` either. Around Ruby 2.0 it became possible to use keyword parameters (the `max: 255` part in your error message) but since version 1.9 this can be simulated using hashes.

The last release of IronRuby I can find is 1.1.3 and it claims to be working towards compatibility with Ruby 1.9 but it seems kind of abandoned. So you can downgrade your gems even further or change your Ruby implementation to MRI or JRuby.

Comment: How do I install the MRI version? The Ruby Installer for Windows doesn't let me select any specific version. And I can't find anything about that on [the installation page](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/).

Comment: Go to https://rubyinstaller.org/ and install the lastest version. You should also install and configure [DevKit](https://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/)

Comment: That is exactly what I did to get my current version of Ruby. But somehow there is no mention of 'MRI' anywhere on that page.

Comment: MRI is what the "standard", `C` based version of ruby is called, IronRuby is a .NET implementation that as I already said seems to be incompatible with current gems due to changes in the language. If you absolutely need to use IronRuby then check for gems that require Ruby versions < 1.9

Comment: Thanks, I downgraded `term-ansicolor` to 1.0.4 and that made it work.

Comment: @Antimony IronRuby is a mostly abandoned implementation of the Ruby language (its latest release was about 6 years ago). You should not use it unless you really, really, really need it. Instead use the normal Ruby implementation (often called MRI) which you can download for Windows at https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/. Generally, when people speak of Ruby and don't further specify the implementation, they mean MRI, the original Ruby implemented in C. Other options are JRuby and Rubinius, but to get started with Ruby, you should use the default implementation.

Comment: Thanks @HolgerJust. Which implementation would you recommend to be able to use Cucumber with .NET? Cuke4nuke?